# Double value cannot be converted to Int64 because it is either infinite or NaN

Tags: ios, swift

Im new to swift and I'm working on a project in swift 3.0 where I have a UISlider to drag. Once I drag it i get the following crash saying "Double value cannot be converted to Int64 because it is either infinite or NaN". My code as bellow. How would I overcome this bug ??. The line that getting crashed is "let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(val), timescale: 1)"...

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {

        let totalsecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        print("Durtion :",totalsecs)
        let val = Float64(sender.value) * totalsecs

        let totalduration = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) as Float64

        if(val != totalduration){

            let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(val), timescale: 1)
            player?.seek(to: seekTime, completionHandler: { (completedSeek) in

            })
        }else{
            print("Slider dragged error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your print statement output - "Duration..."? Why not print sender.value, Float64(sender.value), and totalsecs too? Will probably be pretty obvious once you can see all the values...

Comment: duration is nan

Comment: Did you check the Google hits for `currentitem.duration nan` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to follow the error message...

*"Double value cannot be converted to Int64 because it is either infinite or NaN"* - and you say it's on the `let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(val), timescale: 1)` line...

So... since that line is using `Int64(val)` it's pretty clear ***that*** is where the problem is: `val` is either infinite or NaN.

So... `val` is being set to `let val = Float64(sender.value) * totalsecs`, and `totalsecs` is set by the duration `let totalsecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)` ...

And... you say `duration` is NaN.

Find out why `duration` is NaN, and you have your answer.

Comment: I get both val and duration values nan

Comment: Yes... if `duration` is NaN and you use duration to assign a value to `val`, then ***of course*** `val` will be NaN. *"Find out why `duration` is NaN, and you have your answer."*